# How to @Schedule a task according to a WebSocket Event in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, scheduled-tasks

I would like to create an application in Java to automate trades in my Binance account. Thankfully, [joaopsilva](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/commits?author=joaopsilva) has made it easy through an [open source API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api) which fetches candlesticks through REST Client or WebSocket. I would like to use WebSocket since it is lighter.

I searched in several sources and still I could not find an example project which uses the Spring Boot framework to build an event-driven application which interacts with a connected WebSocket.

If my line of reason is correct, I should define a bean for Spring to instantiate the WebSocket client:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {      
    @Bean
    public BinanceApiWebSocketClient binanceApiWebSocketClient() {
        return BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance().newWebSocketClient(); 
    }
}
```

To interact with the socket event, I created a @Scheduled response, in which I used an arbitrary rate of 1 per second just for testing. I did it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SocketListener {
    @Autowired BinanceApiWebSocketClient client;
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
        client.onCandlestickEvent("ethbtc", CandlestickInterval.ONE_MINUTE, response -> 
System.out.println(response));
    }
}
```

It works. If I launch the Spring application, it successfuly configures the client Bean and it prints the candlestick events. However, every 1 second, what I receive is an enormous chunk of events. It looks like this:

[image]

So, I'm wondering. **Am I doing this correctly?** Would there be a way to Schedule the listener not to receive chunks of events, but to listen the socket exactly when an event happens (not setting delay = 1, which of course causes unnecessary performance issues).

Comment: You have a web socket client... Why would you need a scheduler to trigger it? It don't get your reasoning.. You already have the client, that reacts to incoming events...

Comment: Yes I agree with that seems redundant. I’m probably missing the more adequate approach. Which tool would you use to estabilish an event loop that triggers with the socket stream?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about the correct place to start the event streaming through the websocket client defined as a bean, one of the options is an `ApplicationRunner` bean whose `run()` method will be executed once on application start:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BinanceClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BinanceClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(BinanceApiWebSocketClient binanceApiWebSocketClient) {
        return args -> {
            binanceApiWebSocketClient.onCandlestickEvent("ethbtc",
                                                         CandlestickInterval.ONE_MINUTE,
                                                         response ->
                                                                 System.out.println(response));
        };
    }
}


@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {      
    @Bean
    public BinanceApiWebSocketClient binanceApiWebSocketClient() {
        return BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance().newWebSocketClient(); 
    }
}
```

With the scheduled task you have a new event stream is started with every task execution and you end up having multiple streams of the same events.

Comment: Oh this seems much more neat. I’ll try ir tomorrow and I close the question if it works as expected. Thank you.